# Precognitive badge

Tags: support, badges

I wonder, what are the additional requirements for this badge *besides* following the proposal before it's commited ?

Because as far I recall, I followed the proposal before commitment (there were about 140 followers at the time), yet I'm out of luck so I'm slightly surprised.

Answer (score 1):

> *Followed the Area 51 proposal for this site before it entered the commitment phase*

Here is the [definition from meta](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/71712/should-the-precognitive-badge-be-listed-in-the-list-of-sofu-badges).

[List of all badges](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/67397/list-of-all-badges-with-full-descriptions).